# ImportError: libGL.so.1 : error when accessing Heroku app

Tags: heroku

I have a probem with accessing my heroku app because of following error

```
2020-09-11T10:25:09.492648+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What i already tried is:

1. Add Aptfile with

- libsm6
- libxrender1
- libfontconfig1
- libice6

2. Add buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
3. use opencv-python-headless in requirements

nothing works.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### TL:DR - Add 'libgl1' to Aptfile.

I guess the fix for any type of import error works like this:

If you have library error like **libGL.so.1** you should take the name of the library in lowercase (in this case **'libgl'**) and add the number at the end of the name (in this case it's **'1'**) - so you get a word **libgl1**. Now write that word into **Aptfile**.

If you don't have Aptfile just create it in the root folder - this file does not have any extension.

Comment: To use an `Aptfile` you need to add a buildpack.  Follow the instructions on the buildpack github here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and I added the following line in my `requirements.txt`:

```
opencv-python-headless==4.2.0.32
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Only the problem is the version, remove the specific version. and it will work.

Answer (score 5):

First run

> heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

Create **Aptfile** and add **libgl1**

Answer (score 0):

Put **opencv-python-headless** in requirements.txt without specifying version. Now rebuild again.