# Heroku flask, mediapipe library installation error

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, mediapipe

I able to run the python flask code in heroku server successfully without error.

But if i add a statement "import mediapipe" library, its results with error. even i have added all lines in APTFILE, even though im not abe to solve error,

libGL.so.1: how to clear this error.

and i have already added libsm6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1 libice6 libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1 libgl1-mesa-dev libexample these line in my APTFILE

please help me to solve this issue

libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
libgl1-mesa-glx
libglu1
libgl1-mesa-dev
libexample
these are added already line in my APTFILE

2023-10-10T04:00:03.310821+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-10-10T04:00:03.311110+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-10-10 04:00:03 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)

this is the error log

Even though I'm not able to solve the error

To install mediapipe package in heroku server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: libGL.so.1 : error when accessing Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845382/importerror-libgl-so-1-error-when-accessing-heroku-app)